# how to send an email with the default laravel template

Tags: laravel, email

How can i send an email on laravel by using the default template ? ?

what i mean in the default html template is the same template that used for resetting password for example ...

anyway please ? ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: my problem is not sending an email -- the problem is sending an email with the same template as reset password one

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Laravel 5.3 or 5.4, you should first publish the mail views using:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

That will copy the blade files to resources/views/vendor/mail.
Then the build method of your Mailable class can call the required mail template.

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail) for more details.

Comment: i will try to see the result

Answer (score 1):

This is how I send emails using the Mail class that ships with Laravel.

```
$user = PlaceUserObjectHere;
$emailType = 'Comment';
$emailView = 'emails.standardTemplate';
$emailContent = PlaceContent Object here;
$emailContent['Content'] = 'Place Email Body Here';
$emailSubject = 'Place Subject Line Here ';
$emailContent['Header'] = $emailSubject;
$emailContent['buttonURL'] = '/';
$emailContent['buttonTitle'] = 'Button Text';

Mail::send($emailView, ['user' => $user, 'emailContent' => $emailContent], function ($m) use ($user, $emailSubject) {
                $m->from('support@email.com', 'emailName');
                $m->to($user->first()->email, $user->first()->fname . ' ' . $user->first()->lname)->subject($emailSubject);
            });
```

**Here is the standardTemplate.**

```
<div class='container' text-align="center">
    <h3 class="panel-title navbar-brand">{!! $emailContent['Header'] !!}</h3>
{!! $emailContent['Content'] !!}
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div>
        <a href="{{url($emailContent['buttonURL'])}}" style="background-color:#2a3e68;border:1px solid #2a3e68;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:300px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">{{$emailContent['buttonTitle']}}</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
@include('emails.partial.footer')
        </div>
```

Hope this helps.